# Implementing simple uitableviewcell/collectionviewcell with Facebook Component Kit

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, componentkit

Currently, I have already implemented with normal tableviewcell like this.

[image]

I am now studying about component kit and wana do sth like that view. I am reading through their example WildeGuess. There are very little tutorial or no tutorial for using component kit. How shall I implement to put label in left corner and imageview in left corner also (I can put imageview in the container as in example)?

Comment: if u implement this one kindly post your answer